# bind on second network interface not working

Tags: linux, routing

I have two network interfaces eth0 and usb0.
When eth0 is disconnected and only usb0 is connected everything works.

When both are connected, ping -I or ssh -b does not work when specifying the address of the usb0 interface.

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
172.22.2.0    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     1      0        0 eth0
192.168.2.0    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     1      0        0 usb0
0.0.0.0         172.22.2.1    0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
```

What am I missing?

```
ping -I 192.168.2.10 216.58.217.142
PING 216.58.217.142 (216.58.217.142) from 192.168.2.10 : 56(84) bytes of data.
^C
--- 216.58.217.142 ping statistics ---
6 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 5404ms
```

Also, I don't have root access.

After some questions below, I realize that the defautl gateway is an ip on usb0 when its only usb0 on. When both are on, the default gateway is an ip on eth0.
Anyway to change this behavior without root?

Comment: Do you have another gateway other than `172.22.2.1` when eth0 is disconnected?

Comment: Is your 192.168.*.* actually connected (by some routing path) to the 216.*.*.* network? Doesn't look as if that is the case.

Comment: @Khaled yes, I didn't realize the default changes when its just usb0 - 0.0.0.0         192.168.2.129  0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 usb0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add an IP rule (route based on source IP address) with a separate routing table. The following commands will do the trick:

```
$ sudo ip rule from 192.168.2.10 table 100
$ sudo ip route add default via 192.168.2.129 dev usb0 table 100
```

After that, your `ping -I` command should work. Please, note that `table 100` can be assigned any unused number. This is just an arbitrary number that should be identical in both commands shown above. These two commands tell the kernel to use the IP `192.168.2.129` as default gateway for all packets with source IP of `192.168.2.10`.

Other packets will use the default gateway of main table `172.22.2.1`.

You may need to have a look at Linux advanced routing [documentation](http://lartc.org/lartc.html).

Please, note these commands require root privilege!

Comment: Do note that OP says "Also, I don't have root access.". Not sure if that extends to sudo access as well, but I suspect so...